# Does a function always converge to a point in the co-domain at the point of discontinuity?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, continuity

Given a function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, is it necessary that if $x=t$ is the first point of discontinuity, then $\exists \ y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(t) = y$ would make the function continuous over the interval $(-\infty, t]$?

My hunch was to consider the sequence $x_{n \in \mathbb{N}} = f(t-\frac{\epsilon}{n})$ and say that its limit will be the desired point. But I don't know if every sub-sequence $y_n \subseteq f$ will converge to the same point.

Comment: Look at $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$, $x\ne0$; $f(0)=0$.

Comment: @DavidMitra $f$ is continuous in your example. It does not contradict anything I suppose.

Comment: It is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: @DavidMitra May I ask why you chose $f(0) = 0$ rather than any other number, like $f(0) = 759$?